# apiprotector.net error An item with the same key has already been added. Key: X-API-Protector

Tags: c#, .net, .net-5

ApiProtector.Net (https://apiprotector.net/), gives me error: An element with the same key has already been added. Key: X-API-Protector, when I protect an endpoint with more than one rule.

`[ApiProtector(ApiProtectionType.ByIpAddress, Limit: 10, TimeWindowSeconds: 10, PenaltySeconds: 60)]`
`[ApiProtector(ApiProtectionType.ByIdentity, Limit: 10, TimeWindowSeconds: 10, PenaltySeconds: 60)]`

Comment: What's the stack trace? I'd guess it's a bug in ApiProtector.Net.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution is a bug in ApiProtector.Net.
Try to add more than once in the hader the key: X-API-Protector

Create a class inheriting from ApiProtector, and overwrite the OnActionExecuted method.

```
public class CustomApiProtector : ApiProtector
{
    public CustomApiProtector(ApiProtectionType type, uint limit, uint timeWindowSeconds, uint penaltySeconds ):base(type, limit, timeWindowsSecond, penaltySeconds)
    {

    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {

        base.OnActionExecuted(context);


        IHeaderDictionary headers = context.HttpContext.Response.Headers;
        StringValues locationHeaderValue = string.Empty;
        if (headers.TryGetValue("X-API-Protector", out locationHeaderValue))
        {
            context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Remove("X-API-Protector");
            
        }

      
    }

}
```